# .submit() return false causes weird (to me) behavior

Tags: php, jquery

What I'm trying to get is to count which checkboxes in article list are selected, and I'm writing selected to "toDel" jquery variable.

Then, if "toDel" remains empty, I'd like to stop submiting the form, and if there is any, I'm proceeding by adding "toDel" value to hidden field value.

If selected it all works fine, but once if I click button and no chechboxes are selected, "return false" somehow stops, and I when new checkbox is selected, I can't get into "correct" part of the code.

I've checked here, and figured out that I can't use "return false" so I tried with validator variable, but it behaves the same.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#jqdeleteselected").on("click", function(){
  var toDel='';
      $('.jqchkbx').each(function() {
         if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
          toDel += ($(this).attr('value')+',')
         }
    });
    console.log(toDel);

    $("#send").submit(function() {
        var valid = true;
        if (toDel != '') {

        $('#boxevi').val(toDel);        
        console.log('filled');

        }
        console.log('empty');
        valid = false;


    });         
    return valid;
});
```

});

```
<form method="POST" action='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' name="send" id="send">
<input type="hidden" id="boxevi" name="boxevi" />
<input type="submit" id="jqdeleteselected" value="Obriši označene">
<input type="submit" name="addnew" value="Dodaj novi artikl" /></form><br /></div>';
```

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to handle `submit` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send").submit(function() {
        var toDel='';
          $('.jqchkbx').each(function() {
             if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
              toDel += ($(this).attr('value')+',')
             }
        });
        console.log(toDel);

        if (toDel != '') {
            $('#boxevi').val(toDel);        
            console.log('filled');
        }else{
            console.log('empty');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure (I started using JQuery yesterday, so I'm total noob :) ), because on the same form I have one more button (forgot to add it in HTML code) and it is "Add new article" and I've coded that one through PHP, so If I use only $("#send").submit(function() as you suggested, my Add new is not working any more, that's why I'd like to execute this only on click.

(if this is not the best case scenario, please suggest, then I'll recode and use jquery for both buttons)

Comment: May be your "Add new article" button relies on some variables defined in scope of `submit` event handler? If yes, that just change code I posted to define them in wider scope. And is submit handling I posted works for you?

Comment: yes, your post works perfectly fine for what I have asked, but in big picture, because "delete" now works fine, "add new" does not work at all :)

I have floating function in php called checkaction() where I check all $_POST[] variables from all my forms, and depending on value of the variable (addnewarticle, addnewstaticcontent, editarticle, savearticle) I use different case in my contenthandler. However, if i use only .submit(), this "addnewarticle" button, which is on same form as "delete selected" does not work, but rather behaves exactly as "delete selected"...

Comment: Post the code of "addnewarticle" handler to pastebin, I`ll try to help you organize it

Comment: Hi Timur, I've managed in a meantime, I added additional hidden file to differentiate action delete or add new:
    <input type="hidden" id="boxevi" name="boxevi" />
                                     <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" />
                                     <button onclick="addcheckboxes();if($(\'#boxevi\').val()==\'\'){return false;}$(\'#action\').val(\'delete\');$(\'#formarticle\').submit();">Delete</button>
                                     <button onclick="$(\'#action\').val(\'save\');$(\'#formarticle\').submit();">SAve</button></form><br /></div>';

Answer (score 0):

You only need to handle submit and you can use :checked selector to speed up your check

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").submit(function() {
        var toDel='',
            $this = $(this),
            checkd = $(".jqchkbx:checked");
        checkd.each(function() {
            toDel += $(this).val() + ',';
        });
        console.log(toDel);

        if (checkd.length > 0) {
            $('#boxevi').val(toDel);        
            console.log('filled');
        }else{
            console.log('empty');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but I'm constantly getting "empty" in console, no matter what I select, and it returns false all the time.

Comment: checkboxes are out of the form, so $this.find(".jqchkbx:checked") is always empty. I changed the code to fix my mistake.